# python use query_1 result in query_2 where condition as both the query will run in different sql server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypyodbc

python use query_1 result in query_2 where condition as both the query will run in different sql server

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', host = 'server1', database = 'db1', user = '', password = '', Trusted_Connection = 'yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cnxn1 = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', host = 'server2', database = 'db2', user = '', password = '', Trusted_Connection = 'yes')
cursor1 = cnxn1.cursor()


query = "SELECT top(10) Batch_ID   FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1];"

cursor.execute(query)
Result = cursor.fetchall()

print (Result)

query1="delete FROM [db2].[dbo].[table2] where Batch_ID in (**Result**);" ###i have use 1st query result in this where condition

cursor.execute(query1)
Result1 = cursor1.fetchall()
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask, it isn't very clear from what you wrote

Comment: i need to use 1st query result in 2nd query. the query 1 result is in the form of [('123',),('456',),('789',)]but that need to be converted as ('123','456','789')

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to mess with constructing an `IN` clause for your `DELETE` statement. You can just use a regular `... WHERE Batch_ID = ?` and then pass the list of values to `.executemany`, e.g.

```python
query = "SELECT TOP(10) Batch_ID FROM [db1].[dbo].[table1];"
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
query1 = "DELETE FROM [db2].[dbo].[table2] WHERE Batch_ID = ?;"
cursor.executemany(query1, result)
```